# Angular2 : Life cycle hook in child component when @Input() populated via parent observable data service

Tags: angular

I have built a data service modelled on an article by Cory Rylan that can be seen at https://coryrylan.com/blog/angular-2-observable-data-services.
In my parent component I retrieve a "tag$" as follows:

```
private getTag( id: number ) : void {

    // Subscribe to the observable
    this.tags$ = this.tagService.tags$;

    // Filter the observable looking for the tag we are interested in.
    this.tag$ = this.tagService.tags$ 
         .map(tags => tags.find(tag => tag.id === id));

    let criteria = {'parameters': {}, 'nested': [] };

    this.utilityService.buildParameters( criteria.parameters, [
        {
            'column': 'id',
            'comparison_operator': 'equal',
            'value': id
        }
    ]);

    criteria.nested = ['masters','variants','website_products','ebay_products'];

    this.tagService.load( this.utilityService.encode( criteria ) )
    .subscribe( 
        data => {},
        error =>  {

            this.flashService.command.next({message: 'Error: ' + error, type: 'danger'});
        }
    );        
}
```

I then pass the tag$ value to the child component as:

```
<tag-form [tag]="tag$ | async"></tag-form>
```

In my child controller I am trying to build a reactive form and set the default values of the form to the value of "tag" but i'm struggling to hook into the correct life cycle event.

I've read about ngOnChanges but it appears to be called twice, first time the value of tag is empty. My Child looks like:

```
export class TagFormComponent implements OnInit {

    @Input() tag;
    tagForm: FormGroup;

    constructor( private formBuilder: FormBuilder ) {}

    ngOnInit() {

        console.log('we are inside onInit');
        console.log( this.tag );
    }

    ngOnChanges() {

        console.log('we are inside onChanges');
        console.log( this.tag );
        this.buildForm();
    }

    reset() {

        this.tagForm.reset();
    }

    private buildForm() {

        this.tagForm = this.formBuilder.group({
            id: [ this.tag.id, 
                [
                ]
            ],
            name: [ this.tag.name, 
                [
                    Validators.required
                ]
            ],
            description: [ this.tag.description,
                [
                    Validators.required
                ]
            ]
        });
    }
}
```

I suspect it has something to do with the | async pipe. Can anybody please advise?

Greatly appreciated.

Comment: A couple of concerns...  `// Subscribe to the observable
    this.tags$ = this.tagService.tags$;

    // Filter the observable looking for the tag we are interested in.
    this.tag$ = this.tagService.tags$ 
         .map(tags => tags.find(tag => tag.id === id));` you are setting this.tags$ and then setting it again to your map?  When you use the async pipe, it is expecting an async operation (observable).  You may be ending up with a different type of tags$ than what you are expecting.  Try stepping through your code and make sure your property is as expected.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the feedback. I'm a beginner at Angular but think you have misread my code. The second assignment it to the singular "tag" not "tags". Or have I missed something? The syntax is still quite alien to me.

Comment: Yeah, I didn't see it clearly.  The $ at the end of the properties threw me off.  I'm not sure what it signifies.  Any who, can you step through and see what `@Input() tag;` is becoming?  It looks like you need an interface to describe `tag` and give the property an explicit type.  The default `any` should work but not very clean.  You can also make `tag` have a getter and setter so you can break point where it gets set to see if the value is expected.  Do you have a plunker?